# Retrieving data from thingspeak website to android app

Tags: java, android

i am fresher in android development, i am currently developing an IOT Project, in which my friend send an data from kit to the thingspeak in graph format like temperature, humidity and i want to show this graph and each and every graph variable in textview as well as table format. updated value show in table format.
please help me to show this data in table format and tell me how to show graph value in textview.

Comment: what exactly is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source tool to show ThingSpeak channel data in a table view. I call it [IoT Debugger](https://github.com/nothans/iot-debugger). For a [demo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/nothans/iot-debugger/blob/master/app/thingspeak.html), just change the channel and read key and press the play button.